# Stripe Clone Customer and Create Direct Charge on Connected Account

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a direct charge on a connected account in Stripe.  I have been going through docs on Stripe and posts here but just can't seem to get it working.

The customer and their payment method(s) are stored on the platform account.  I am trying to clone the customer on the connected account but do not want to store their payment method(s) on the connected account.  According to the docs I can generate a one-time-use payment intent by not attaching it to the customer I'm trying to create on the connected account.

When trying to clone the customer, I am getting the error:

`StripeInvalidRequestError: The customer must have an active payment source attached.`

In the code below I am making sure that the payment method is attached to the platform customer, and when I go to the console I see the payment method for them and it is marked "default."

Any help appreciated!

```
const customerId = 'cus_xxx'; // platform customer id
const paymentMethod = 'pm_xxxx'; // platform customer payment method

const getDefaultCard = async (customer) => {
  const { invoice_settings } = await stripe.customers.retrieve(customer);
  return invoice_settings ? invoice_settings.default_payment_method : null;
};

const getCards = async (customer) => {
  if (!customer) {
    return [];
  }
  const default_card = await getDefaultCard(customer);
  const { data } = await Stripe.stripe.paymentMethods.list({
    customer,
    type: "card",
  });
  if (!data) return [];
  return data.map(({ id, card: { last4, exp_month, exp_year, brand } }) => ({
    id,
    last4,
    exp_month,
    exp_year,
    brand,
    default: id === default_card,
  }));
};

// check to see if the current payment method is 
// attached to the platform customer
const cards = await getCards(customerId);

let found = cards.filter((card) => card.id === paymentMethod).length > 0;

// if the card is not found, attach it to the platform customer
if (!found) {
  const res = await Stripe.stripe.paymentMethods.attach(paymentMethod, {
    customer: customerId,
  });
}

const defaultCards = cards.filter((card) => card.default);

if (!defaultCards || !defaultCards.length) {
  // attach a default payment source to the user before
  // cloning to the connected account
  await stripe.customers.update(user.cus_id, {
    invoice_settings: {
      default_payment_method: paymentMethod,
    },
  });
}


// Get customer token - Results in ERROR
const token = await stripe.tokens.create(
  {
    customer: customerId,
    card: paymentMethod,
  },
  {
    stripeAccount,
  }
);

/** DOESN'T GET PAST TOKEN CREATION ABOVE **/

// clone customer
const newCustomer = await stripe.customers.create(
  {
    source: token.id,
    card: paymentMethod,
  },
  {
    stripeAccount,
  }
);

const amount = 1000;
const application_fee_amount = 100;

const intent = await Stripe.stripe.paymentIntents.create(
  {
    customer: newCustomer.id,
    amount,
    currency: "usd",
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    payment_method: paymentMethod,
    description: "Test Connected Direct Charge",
    application_fee_amount,
  },
  {
    stripeAccount,
  }
);

// Now confirm payment
const result = await Stripe.stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(intent.id, {
  payment_method: paymentMethod,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to clone a Payment Method on your platform account to a Token on your connected account.  This is not possible; Payment Methods are a newer Stripe API that are not directly compatible with Tokens (an older API).

You should be [cloning the Payment Method on the platform to a Payment Method on the connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#cloning-payment-methods) instead using code like this:

```
const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.create({
  customer: '{{CUSTOMER_ID}}',
  payment_method: '{{PAYMENT_METHOD_ID}}',
}, {
  stripeAccount: '{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was approaching it with the platform customer not having a payment method and saving/attaching it during the payment intent process then trying to clone it.  Since I am loading the frontend stripe js on the page using the connected account id, I cannot confirm the new payment method from my setup intent. Once I created a  payment method on the platform customer account and started from there everything worked as noted in my answer above. I will just have to have a separate workflow for adding a payment method before the user checks out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by first making sure that a payment method exists on the platform for the user.  Then in my payment intent the following successfully clones the customer and the payment method and charges successfully:

```
// clone payment method
const cloned_pm = await stripe.paymentMethods.create({
        customer,         // platform customer id
        payment_method,   // platform payment method for platform customer
      },{
        stripeAccount
      });

// create token to customer
const token = await stripe.tokens.create({
          customer,              // platform customer id
          card: payment_method,  // platform payment method as above
      },{
          stripeAccount
      });

// clone customer
const newCustomer = await stripe.customers.create({
          source: token.id,
      },{
          stripeAccount
      });

// create intent - used the cloned customer and payment methods
const intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
        {
          customer: newCustomer.id,
          amount: 1000,
          application_fee_amount: 100,
          currency: "usd",
          payment_method_types: ["card"],
          payment_method: cloned_pm.id,    
          ...         
        },
        {
          stripeAccount,
        }
      );
```

Then on the front-end client:

```
const { error, paymentIntent } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
      payment_intent_secret,
      { payment_method: cloned_payment_method_id }
    );
```